How to automatically scroll to a column
I have checked the docs and have gotten no progress trying to auto scroll to a certain column. I have a column I want to scroll to by default and could not figure it out.
I have used https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid//grid-api/#reference-scrolling-ensureIndexVisible but the docs do not specify what a key refers to in a column or I am missing something.
